# Oracle - Join multiple columns trying different combinations

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I'll try to explain my problem:
I need to find the most efficient way to join two table on 4 columns, but data is really crappy so there could be cases where I can join only on 3 or 2 columns because the fourth and/or third were stored badly (with spaces, zeros, dashes,...)
I should try to achieve something like this:

````
select * from table a
join table b
on a.key1=b.key1
and a.key2=b.key2
or a.key3=b.key3
or a.key4=b.key4```
````

I already performed some data quality but the number of records is really high (table a is 300k records and table b is about 25M records).
I know that the example I provided is not efficient and it would be better making separate joins and then "union" them, but I'm asking you if there could be some better way to do it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: So you consider every match on at least two columns a row match? Won't this produce an awful lot of false positives?

Comment: How are the two tables related? 1:n or m:n? I.e. are you simply looking for the best matching table b row for every row in table a for instance? Is any of the four columns reliable and must hence match? Or are they all unreliable and one row may match on key1/key3 and another on key2/key4?

Comment: can you give a few examples of bad data ? Sql  and relational databases are meant to work with structured and well-formed data, if your source data is of low quality , you might want to first clean it up (in some automated ways, hopefully)

Comment: First of all, thank you for answering!
Probably I haven't described precisely the problem, as some said, but you partially get the point.
The fact is that there are two different tables, coming from two different applications, that must be joined on four columns with their respective keys, but one of the two tables it's been populated with manual insert, so the data (despite having applied data quality and recovered lots of rows) sometimes isn't correct. I need to mandatory join them, in first place on the 4 colums, then, if nothing is returned, on 3, then 2 until the last one (worst case).

Answer (score 0):

You haven't explained your problem very well, so let's create an example:

1. There is a table of clients and a table of orders. Both are not related via keys, because both are imported from different systems. Your task is now to find the client per order.
2. Both tables contain the client's last name, first name, city, and a client number. However, these columns are optional in the order table (but either last name or client number are always given). And sometimes a first name or city may be abbreviated or misspelled (e.g. J./James, NY/New York, Cris/Chris).

So, if the order contains a client number, we have a match and are done. Otherwise the last name must match. In the latter case we look at first name and city, too. Do both match? Only one? Neither?

We use `RANK` to rank the clients per order and pick the best matches. Some orders will end up with exactly one match, others will have ties and we must examine the data manually then (the worst case being no client number and no last name match because of a misspelled name).

```
select *
from
(
  select
    o.*,
    c.*,
    rank() over 
    (
      partition by o.order_number
      order by 
      case
        when c.client_number = o.client_number then 1
        when c.last_name = o.last_name and c.first_name = o.first_name and c.city = o.city then 2
        when c.last_name = o.last_name and (c.first_name = o.first_name or c.city = o.city) then 3
        when c.last_name = o.last_name then 4
        else 5
      end
    ) as rnk
  from orders o
  left join clients c on c.client_number = o.client_number or c.last_name = o.last_name
) ranked
where rnk = 1
order by order_number;
```

I hope this gets you an idea how to write such a query and you will be able to adapt this concept to your case.

Comment: First of all, thank you for answering!
Probably I haven't described precisely the problem, as some said, but you partially get the point.
The fact is that there are two different tables, coming from two different applications, that must be joined on four columns with their respective keys, but one of the two tables it's been populated with manual insert, so the data (despite having applied data quality and recovered lots of rows) sometimes isn't correct. I need to mandatory join them, in first place on the 4 colums, then, if nothing is returned, on 3, then 2 until the last one (worst case).

Comment: Oops, my query missed the most importat part: `where rnk = 1` so as to stick only with the best matching rows. So, it seems your ranking is like `case when a.col1 = b.col1 and a.col2 = b.col2 and a.col3 = b.col3 and a.col4 = b.col4 then 1 when a.col1 = b.col1 and a.col2 = b.col2 and a.col3 = b.col3 then 2 ...`.